# RenderTransform RotateTransform Blurry Image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, bitmap

I have the following custom `UserControl` that represents a card in my application:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:Core="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Namespace="clr-namespace:MyApp" xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:MyApp.Properties" Core:Class="MyApp.Card" Height="176" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="83" UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <UserControl.LayoutTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <ScaleTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </UserControl.LayoutTransform>
    <UserControl.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <ScaleTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </UserControl.RenderTransform>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Namespace:ImagesConverter Core:Key="ImagesConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Canvas Core:Name="Layout">
        <Image Core:Name="Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding Source={Core:Static Properties:Resources.Cards}, Converter={StaticResource ImagesConverter}}" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Image.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry Core:Name="Clipping" Rect="0,0,83,176"/>
            </Image.Clip>
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform Core:Name="Translation" X="0" Y="0"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Rectangle Core:Name="Highlight" Canvas.Left="-2" Canvas.Top="-2" Height="180" Opacity="0.7" Stroke="#FFFFF500" StrokeThickness="3" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="87"/>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

As you can see... I have a bit PNG image containing all the card faces and then, when I create a new card passing `Suit` and `Rank` enum values in constructor, I calculate the correct clipping rectagle and translation for the image.
Everything works like a charm... except when I try to animate my card with a `Storyboard` that requires a 90° rotation. Here is my code (the `Storyboard` is defined in `MainWindow.Resources`):

```
<DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00.4" Duration="00:00:00.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="90"/>
```

And here is the result:

[image]

[image]

I can't understand what's going on... but the images gets somehow stretched and becomes very blurry as you can see. I tried using `UseLayoutRounding="True"` in my card control and also `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` in my `MainWindow` as suggested somewhere else... but it's not working!
Of course... if I rotate the card using `LayoutTransform` instead of `RenderTransform` everything works perfectly and the card is not blurry... but I can't make the card rotate around it's center and my animation requires a 90° rotation from the center. Animating `Canvas.Top` for half of the card height together with layout rotation looks to me like a very unbrilliant solution... and it also makes my animation looks very bad.
Can you suggest me a solution please?

[EDIT] I tried to use `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"` and `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"`... but it becomes even worse:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the underlying image, and so the layout, had an odd value as Width (83). RenderTransformOrigin, even if set to "0.5,0.5", was probably rounding up or down that value resulting in a very bad rendering.
Changing both the image and layout Width to a even value (82), totally resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changeing the `RenderOptions` on the `Image` and see if you can find a setting that works, I have added an example of settings I use for this exact situation in my application

```
   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
   RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
```

Example:

```
    <Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
           RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
           Core:Name="Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding Source={Core:Static Properties:Resources.Cards}, Converter={StaticResource ImagesConverter}}" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Core:Name="Clipping" Rect="0,0,83,176"/>
        </Image.Clip>
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform Core:Name="Translation" X="0" Y="0"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
```

Comment: It does not seem as blurry, just bad qualitiy, perhaps try ` RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"` with `SnapToDevicePixels="True"`

Comment: Also setting `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on the `Canvas` may help.

Answer (score 1):

You indicated that using `LayoutTransform` works perfectly without blurring the image. Have you tried using it and specifying the center as the pivot of rotation?

Something like:

```
<Image ...>
  <Image.LayoutTransform>
    <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="90"/>
  </Image.LayoutTransform>
</Image>
```

Comment: Yes... seems not to e recognized.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tommaso Belluzzo said, this is cause from RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
Your answer above really solved my question.
Allow me to show my code as following:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bm = null;
//RotateTransform(angle) with RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" might cause blurry if the width or height is odd,
using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path))
{
    int width = bitmap.Width;
    int height = bitmap.Height;
    if (0 != width % 2) width ++;
    if (0 != height % 2) height ++;
    bm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);

    bm.SetResolution(96, 96);
    using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing. Graphics.FromImage(bm))
    {
        //I don't want to do anything which may modify(resize) the original image.
        g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
        g.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    }
    //bm.Save(directory+@"\tmp.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);

}
//.....(show bm)
```