# Image in PictureBox Become Blurry While Rotating

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to rotate an image that is in side of a PictureBox in a C# WinForm. I rotate the image with every tick of the timer1 (Interval = 100). As I am rotating, however, the image becomes blurrier and blurrier. I am not sure if there is a way to fix this. I have enabled the Form to be double buffered.

Here is the code I am using:

```
public static Image RotateImage(Image img, float rotationAngle)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
    bmp.SetResolution(img.HorizontalResolution, img.VerticalResolution);

    Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    gfx.TranslateTransform((float)bmp.Width / 2, (float)bmp.Height / 2);

    gfx.RotateTransform(-rotationAngle);
    gfx.TranslateTransform(-(float)bmp.Width / 2, -(float)bmp.Height / 2);

    gfx.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));

    gfx.Dispose();

    return bmp;

}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image bmp = Form1.RotateImage(pictureBox1.Image, 10);

    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
```

Comment: Look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906448/rendertransform-rotatetransform-blurry-image)

Comment: @Icemanind I looked at that question, it doesn't really help. My image is a 64x64, so I do not have the fractional divisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider keeping your original image around, and each time you rotate, calculate the new image by applying the cumulative rotation to the original image.

What you're seeing is an unavoidable consequence of the rotation, which can only approximate the original image given the finite number of pixels it has to work with.  You're seeing approximations of approximations, and they'll just get worse each time you rotate.

Comment: I am not sure how I would do this...I am assuming I would need a class variable to keep the cumulative rotation, but I am not sure how to rotate the original image.

Comment: Yes, use a class member to keep the cumulative rotation.  Also keep the original image around as a class member, and then in your `timer1_Tick` method, rather than `Form1.RotateImage(pictureBox1.Image, 10)`, do `Form1.RotateImage(originalImage, cumulativeRotation);`

Comment: Thanks! That was so much easier than I was thinking.